# Droid x2 Android 2.3.4 layout issue

Tags: android-layout

I have been writing apps for my Droid x2 using the new Android update 2.3.4.
The layout with of a simple test app show a margin on the left, right, and buttom side of the screen.
How do I get the full real-estate of the screen?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
>
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Hello World, MainActivity"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Screen shot: http://jasonfoglia.com/img/DROIDX2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I think i solved it.
Insert this line into the Manifest and it works.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="8"></uses-sdk>
```

For more information look at this site: http://realmike.org/blog/2010/12/21/multiple-screen-sizes-with-processing-for-android/